# ReactJS: How do I properly convert from styled-components to MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I want to migrate from styled-components to MUI v5xxx, I have some styling work on styled-components but after I convert the code to the MUI some of them don't work properly, for example, I have a `container` supposed to be hovering an `infostyle` but nothing happen

**Hover Script**

```js
const StyledInfo = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  opacity: 0,
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  position: "absolute",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  zIndex: 3,
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  transition: "all 0.5s ease",
}));

const StyledContainer = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  flex: 1,
  minWidth: "320px",
  height: "400px",
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  backgroundColor: "#F7BB62",
  backgroundImage: `url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/crissxcross.png")`,
  color: "#ffffff",
  position: "relative",
  cursor: "pointer",

  "&:hover ${StyledInfo}": {
    opacity: 1,
  },
}));
```

as you can see on this `"&:hover ${StyledInfo}": {....}` doesn't work

**Another example, when adding props**

```js
const Arrow= styled("img")(({ theme,props }) => ({
  left: ${(props) => props.direction === "left" && "10px"},
  right: ${(props) => props.direction === "right" && "10px"},
}));
```

on this case `${(props) => props.direction === "left" && "10px"}` doesn't work

## What I've tried

- **Using backtick**

I have no clue how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Are you using emotion? If you are using emotion (highly recommended over styled-components), you can simply use `import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles`, and it works identically.

If you use emotion, you need to follow https://mui.com/system/styled/#how-to-use-components-selector-api to add the babel plugin, in order to use Child selector

babel config

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    [
      "@emotion",
      {
        importMap: {
          "@mui/system": {
            styled: {
              canonicalImport: ["@emotion/styled", "default"],
              styledBaseImport: ["@mui/system", "styled"]
            }
          },
          "@mui/material/styles": {
            styled: {
              canonicalImport: ["@emotion/styled", "default"],
              styledBaseImport: ["@mui/material/styles", "styled"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

With regards to the following code

```
const Arrow= styled("img")(({ theme,props }) => ({
  left: ${(props) => props.direction === "left" && "10px"},
  right: ${(props) => props.direction === "right" && "10px"},
}));
```

Your condition is actually invalid. e.g. if your `props.direction`, your `left` property becomes `false` which is not a valid value.

Probably a better way to write this component would be

```
const Arrow= styled("img", { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => !['left', 'right'].includes(prop))(({ theme,direction }) => ({
  left: ${direction === 'left' ? '10px' : 'auto'},
  right: ${direction === 'right' ? '10px' : 'auto'},
}));
```

Update:

in this code block, you are using " instead of `, which means StyledInfo is being read as plain text.

```
 "&:hover ${StyledInfo}": {
    opacity: 1,
  },
```

Try changing to

```
 `&:hover ${StyledInfo}`: {
    opacity: 1,
  },
```

Comment: I think im using `import { styled } from "@mui/material";` what about `"&:hover ${StyledInfo}": {....}`

Comment: it's actually `@mui/material/styles`

Comment: since you are using emotion please follow the link in the answer to install the babel plugin

Comment: I have tried all of that but it seems a new problem coming, the eslint give ` unexpected token `  in this line ` &: hover ${StyledInfo}: {....}`

Comment: added a update to answer and see if it works for u. If it doesn't, kindly create a codesandbox.io example, and i will edit codes for you.

Comment: sure here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/wavenitem-5jubbm

Comment: are you using create-react-app? I havent been using create-react-app, and have been using nextJS all these years, **but** in order to use custom babel, you need to install react-app-rewired and customize-cra. If you need help, you can google "create react app custom babel"